# Redmine variables not being replaced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, redmine

I recently moved my redmine installation to a new server and for some reason the variables aren't being replaced any more. For example, this is what I see for the issue tracking:

```
Bug: 0 open / {{total}}
Feature: 0 open / {{total}}
Support: 0 open / {{total}}
Maintenance: 0 open / {{total}}
```

This is happening all over my install, can't figure it out! Thought it could be a db charset issue but changed it to UTF-8 (from latin), restarted passenger and still no luck.

Any ideas gratefully received!

Comment: If you haven't upgraded past 1.0.5 yet, consider upgrading to ChiliProject (http://www.chiliproject.org), a fork of Redmine that is likely to outpace the development of Redmine itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with the most recent version of the i18n gem. See [bug#7534](http://www.redmine.org/issues/7534) for instructions.

Comment: Perfect, for reference I had to make sure only version 4.2 of the i18n gem was installed.